# When updating constraint, the view si positioned wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

something very odd happens to my code. On iOS 8 everything is ok, but there are troubles with iOS 7.
There is a code where I update constraint:

```
- (void)setHasInfo:(BOOL)hasInfo {
    if (hasInfo) {
        self.infoViewTopConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    else {
        self.infoViewTopConstraint.constant = - self.infoView.bounds.size.height;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    _hasInfo = hasInfo;
}
```

And in iOS 8 works, but on iOS 7 the position is wrong. I check with NSLog and the height of the infoView is 130. So then I changed the code to:

```
- (void)setHasInfo:(BOOL)hasInfo {
    if (hasInfo) {
        self.infoViewTopConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    else {
        self.infoViewTopConstraint.constant = - 130;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    _hasInfo = hasInfo;
}
```

And suddenly everything works. So in first example if I log the infoView y position if get 62 or -68 but in second example I get 0 or -130. I think this is very strange, because if you look at the code you'll see that when BOOL = YES the constraint is set to 0 but if I logged it in console once is 0 and next time is 62. How is it possible?

Here are the screenshots from simulator:
1. Info View should be hidden (but it's partly visible)
[image: Info View should be hidden]
1. Info View should be visible (but it's partly hidden)
[image: Info View should be visible]
2. Info View is hidden
[image: Info View is hidden]
2. Info View is visible
[image: Info View is visible]

Comment: Do you use constraints relative to margins? Because this won't work on iOS 7

Comment: No, I checked and I used normal constraints. All views that matters here are UIView. Every other elements on screen don't matter right now.